# can we use $random in system verilog with seed argument?

Tags: random, verilog, system-verilog

can I use $random(seed) in order to generate same value for a variable in system verilog?

```
module test();
logic[1:0] a,b:
integer seed;
initial begin
repeat (3)
begin
seed = 20;
a = $random(seed);
b=$random;
$display("a=%h,b=%h",a,b):
end
end
endmodule
```

For the above code I ma always getting value of 'a' as '0'. Cant we use $random with seed? Because when I changed it to $urandom(seed) it works as expected. I read in so many places that I can use $random with seed argument.
can someone please help on this

Also for $urandom(seed) in the below code

```
module test();
logic[1:0] a,b:
integer seed,seed1;
initial begin
repeat (3)
begin
seed = 20;
seed1 = 55;
a = $urandom(seed);
$display("a first random=%h",a);
a = $urandom(seed1);
$display("a second random =%h",a);
b=$random;
$display("a=%h,b=%h",a,b);
end
end
endmodule
```

for the above code eventhough if I am giving seed1 and seed2 as argument for $urandom in different randomisation it is taking the same value eventhough the seed number is changing inside module? Is it expected or if we are giving different seeds as argument to $urandom does the value needs to be hanged or not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are setting `seed=20` every time through the loop, so you always get the same random values. In SystemVerilog, just use `$urandom;` and set a global seed from your simulator's command line.

Comment: I was just trying out the seed option along with $random and $urandom just for learning. I tried this seed=20 with so many numbers in all of these the value became 0 not even getting 1 what may be the cause for this? A the same time when I used with $urandom it got a value other than 0. If you can see I have updated my qustion with one more doubt can you just have a look on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I agree same random value but the random value is always 0  with any seed value I am giving Not only with seed = 20

Comment: try `seed=201`. The distribution of values is very poor for `$random`.